# How to set a limit on the number of uploaded images?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I used ckeditor 5 library for my textarea

I have this JS code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#history-description'), {
            "toolbar": ["imageUpload", "bold", "link", "bulletedList", "uploadImage", "blockQuote"],
            "ckfinder": {
                "uploadUrl": "uploadImage.php",
                "options": {
                    resourceType: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg']
                }
            },
        }).then(editor => {
            // editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').on('change:uploadTotal', evt => {
            //     console.log('Image uploaded evt');
            //     console.log(evt);
            // });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
```

How to set a limit on the number of uploaded images?

For example: the maximum number of uploaded files can only be 10

Comment: that'd be better for your backend to handle

Comment: i cant
when i select 100 pictures it will send me 100 different requests to add pictures
That is, the server will think that each request = 1 picture

Comment: Sure you could, you could count the amount of existing images. This could be done in a couple of different ways